# Is it safe to wipe off iPhone screen with a wet wipe?

Tags: iphone, screen, macos

I am wondering if cleaning an iPhone screen with a wet wipe could have any negative impact on the touch-sensitivity of the screen.

Answer (score 1):

I would not use a wet one, but damp.

With wet you might crate drops that can sneek in in places they should not.